# Is the first chapter by Eutropius in Roma Aeterna (Lingua Lataina Per Se II) unedited?

Tags: lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, eutropius

Chapter 46 of *Roma Aeterna* titled 'Post Regos Exactos' which is taken from Eutropius' Brevarium. The subtitle of each chapter has hitherto included some note about the extract being edited by the author, but for this chapter it doesn't. Am I to understand this is Eutropius entirely unedited? I'm just curious because I find it a lot easier than the preceding few extracts from Livy.

Comment: I'm not sure about this passage, but as a general rule, literally any other author will be easier than Livy.

Comment: [Compare](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/eutropius/eutropius1.shtml#9) for yourself …